# Do you need health insurance if you do a short stay under a national visa in Germany and already have a travel insurance?

Tags: germany

I live in Kuwait and am applying for German national student visa. They asked me for travel insurance, and I have got it. Now, the issue is, in some other documents, they refer to the insurance as health insurance, and I am confused, if I need travel health insurance on top of travel insurance to stay in Germany.

Some sites say it is neccesary for everyone, but would it still be true if the period of stay is less than 2 weeks? Because, I heard if it is in that duration then you don't even have to do residence registration.

Comment: I think that often terminology used by different sources is not exact and *"travel insurance"*  may used as an equivalent  for *"health insurance for a traveller"*  in the regard that you're required to have coverage for unexpected medical and health care expenses that may occur during your stay. Of course travel insurance typically covers more than   just  health care insurance alone and often includes additional things like for example trip cancellation or interruption coverage, baggage and personal effects coverage, rental property and rental car coverage  and/or accidental death coverage.

Comment: Seems so the health insurance coverage in my tavel doc is only for wmergencies

Comment: Travel insurance usually limits the length of any trip and/or the total amount of days covered during a year.

Comment: "Only for emergencies." Exactly: they want to know if you will be a burden on emergency services, not if you have a verucca plan.

Comment: "...to live in Germany..." or "...two week visit..."? The answers might be different.

Comment: For a student visa, you should ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange, not here. A short stay with a national visa sounds strange.

Comment: @SBrian Travel insurance by definition covers only short trips and only emergencies

Comment: @SBrian Yes, travel insurance covers more than just medical expenses, but the public authorities are only interested in the medical expenses. They don't care about your lost luggage and cancelled flights, but they care a lot about unpaid hospital bills.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would I need health insurance if I come to Germany for short stay under national visa?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/26438/would-i-need-health-insurance-if-i-come-to-germany-for-short-stay-under-national)

Answer (score 2):

As with all employees, you must be insured **at the latest** on the first day of work. For students, this is the first day of the semester. Until then you should be covered by a normal travel insurance as any other visitor.

During the enrollment process you will probably be advised to select a **health provider** (**Krankenkasse**) and that you must inform them which one you have selected since they will cover around 50% of the costs.

Health providers offer special rates for students, so you should supply them with a confirmation that you have been accepted as a student.

They will then issue you a certificate that you are insured by them and the date it starts. The earliest possible date is the date of the enrollment.

When you apply for your **residence permit** card (which replaces the national visa) they will also want to see this certificate.